# Django radio button value is not rendering

Tags: python, django

I created a radio field in my form, after registering the user I can't see what he checked.

**user.html:**

```
<p>{{ user.profile.name }}</p>
<p>{{ user.profile.email }}</p>
<p>{{ user.profile.choices }}</p> #not rendering anything, can't see the value after I logged in
<p>{{ user.choices }}</p> #(just in case) not rendering value
```

here is my code :

**models.py:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from utilisateur.models import Profile

class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES=[('clients','Je cherche une secretaire.'), ('secretaires','J\'offre mes services.')]
    choices = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
         model = Profile
         fields = ("name", "email", "choices")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.choices = self.cleaned_data['choices']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

What should I do in order the see the value of what I checked after I registered an user ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to miss a `choices` field in your `Profile` class, therefore the `profile` does not get updated. Just try to add another char field in your `Profile` model:

```
choices = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

On the other hand, if you do not want `choices` to be permanently stored you can store it in the user [`session`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/). For this you would have to update the `MyRegistrationForm` class:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
   CHOICES=[('clients','Je cherche une secretaire.'), ('secretaires','J\'offre mes services.')]
   choices = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

   class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ("name", "email")

   def save(self, commit=True):
       user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
       ## In your session variable you create a field choices and store the user choice
       self.request.session.choices = self.cleaned_data['choices']

       if commit:
          user.save()
       return user

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       ## Here you pass the request from your view
       self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
       super(MyRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, when you instantiate a `MyRegistrationForm` in `View` you should pass the `request` variable:

```
f = MyRegistrationForm(request=request)
```

With this, you can access the `choices` field in [`session`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/) variable until the user `session` closes. So in **user.html** you would display it as:

```
<p>{{ request.session.choices }}</p>
```